# Rails - Association Issue When Building an Authentication Table w/ Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, associations, omniauth

I'm trying to build a Rails app that allows users to sign-in via Facebook or Twitter and am trying to build an Authentication table so that a User can have multiple Authentications for logging in.

I've managed to set up Facebook, but have had trouble setting up logic for Twitter because they do not return an email. The issue I'm running into is that after setting everything up, calling User.authentications returns a blank response. There is also a secondary question about how I should override Devise's password_required?

This is my User.rb (omitting unrelated stuff):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter]

has_many :posts
has_many :authentications

def self.from_omniauth(auth, current_user)
  authorization = Authentication.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid.to_s, 
                                      :token => auth.credentials.token, 
                                      :secret => auth.credentials.secret).first_or_initialize


  #Twitter only provides email via API with elevated permissions
  if authorization.user.blank? && auth.provider != 'twitter'

    @koala = Koala::Facebook::API.new(auth.credentials.token)
    @user_info = @koala.get_object(:me, { fields: [:first_name, :last_name, :email]})

    user = current_user.nil? ? User.where('email = ?', @user_info['email']).first : current_user

    if user.blank?
      user = User.new
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      user.first_name = @user_info['first_name']
      user.last_name = @user_info['last_name']
      user.email = @user_info['email']
      user.save
    end
    authorization.user = user
    authorization.save
  end

  if authorization.user.blank? && auth.provider == 'twitter'
    @uid = auth.uid
    @existing_record = Authentication.where(:provider => 'twitter', :uid => @uid).first
    @user_record = @existing_record.blank? ? User.new : @existing_record.user
    user = current_user.nil? ? @user_record : current_user
    if user.new_record?
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      #Twitter only returns full name
      @fullname = auth['info']['name'].split(' ')
      user.first_name = @fullname[0]
      user.last_name = @fullname[1]
      authorization.user = user
      authorization.save
      user.save

      #The following line shows up blank and I don't know why
      puts user.authentications

    else
      authorization.user = user
      authorization.save
   end
end
authorization.user
end
```

This is my Authentication.rb:

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

And this is my Schema:

```
  create_table "authentications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "token"
    t.string   "secret"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.string   "profile_page"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.datetime "oauth_expires_at"
  end
```

I feel like I'm missing something very basic in setting up my associations, but I can't seem to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As an unrelated issue, I also need to override Devise's password_required. Will this work once I solve the above issue?

```
def password_required?
    super && authentications.blank?
end
```

Comment: Do you for sure have authentication records with that user's id in the user_id field?

Comment: I do not, and this is likely causing the issue. The Authentication record is being created, but the user_id value is nil.

Also, when I try to console.log the user.id in the User model, I get a blank response. 

I feel like some cyclical issue is happening where creating the association tries to save the user which cannot save because the email is empty.

Comment: Also I've changed the schema to allow for null emails for users, so it's just Devise making an issue of the empty email